# How to select drop down VBA and click it

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have a few items in a drop down menu and I want to choose one of them. Searching through the `options` tag in HTML, I was able to select it in the drop down, but the pre-settings that each one of the items have **is not loaded**. I think it's because I'm not "choosing" the item with the `select` tag. Does anyone knows how to solve that?

```
    Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")

    For Each opt In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("option")
        If opt.innerText = "Tracker Availability" Then
            Debug.Print "found it"
            opt.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next opt
```

HTML:

```html
<select style="width: 100px; height: 33px; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 2px;" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedScratchPad" ng-options="s.name for s in $ctrl.scratchPads track by s.name" ng-change="$ctrl.scratchPadSelected($ctrl.selectedScratchPad)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched"><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.selectedScratchPad === null --><option ng-if="$ctrl.selectedScratchPad === null" value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Select Export</option><!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.selectedScratchPad === null --><option label="G&amp;T" value="G&amp;T">G&amp;T</option><option label="Relatório semanal" value="Relatório semanal">Relatório semanal</option><option label="CBs current" value="CBs current">CBs current</option><option label="Tracker Availability" value="Tracker Availability">Tracker Availability</option><option label="INV 5-1 Trackers target" value="INV 5-1 Trackers target">INV 5-1 Trackers target</option><option label="INV 5-1 Trackers current" value="INV 5-1 Trackers current">INV 5-1 Trackers current</option><option label="INV 5-1 Trackers availability" value="INV 5-1 Trackers availability">INV 5-1 Trackers availability</option><option label="PVSyst Input" value="PVSyst Input">PVSyst Input</option></select>
```

Edit1: Here it is a couple of pictures that demonstrates what I meant with the pre-settings not loaded:

[image: when opt.Selected = True]
[image: When I manually change the drop down menu value by selecting what I want]

Pic-1: when opt.Selected = True
Pic-2: When I manually change the drop down menu value by selecting what I want

Comment: You can try to set the value using it's class name like IE.document.getElementByClassName("ng-valid").Value = "CBs current" If your dropdown has ID than you can try like this IE.document.getElementById("cb1").Value = "CBs current" Ref: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the _not loaded_? Do you mean that the option tags have no values until you have clicked on the select tag? Can you share what the html looks like in the node loaded state?

Comment: @Qharr of course, my friend! Sorry about that, I was in a rush yesterday and I forgot to do so! Thank you for the help on that one! I'll see your answer to this one and in a few minutes I'll update this post!

Comment: Is the url private? Or login based?

Comment: It's login based. I updated the HTML snippet because I realized it was missing an element. I think I have to set the property *ng-if="$ctrl.selectedScratchPad === null"* somehow... I tried to access the VALUE of the class "ng-binding ng-scope" but it didn't work.

Comment: I also noticed that it *never* enters in this if block `If objCollection(j).getAttribute("class") = "ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" Then`, probably because the code isn't finding  this particular class of the `select` tag

Comment: For testing purpose,Try to check for the first class only using get attribute like If objCollection(j).getAttribute("class") = "ng-valid" then